# Kronecker product on a matrix with structured blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, block-matrices, kronecker-product

I'm currently attempting to write a symmetric matrix with structured blocks into Kronecker-factorized form, but I'm not sure if the task is possible at all. My matrix takes the following form:

$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
a I_1 & \mathbf{0} & gI_1 & \mathbf{0} & iI_1 & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & bI_2 & \mathbf{0} & hI_2 & \mathbf{0} & jI_2 \\
g I_1 & \mathbf{0} & cI_1 & \mathbf{0} & kI_1 & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & hI_2 & \mathbf{0} & dI_2 & \mathbf{0} & lI_2 \\
i I_1 & \mathbf{0} & kI_1 & \mathbf{0} & eI_1 & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & j I_2 & \mathbf{0} & lI_2 & \mathbf{0} & fI_2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $I_1, I_2$ are identity matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{d_1},\mathbb{R}^{d_2}$ respectively, and $a,b,\cdots,l$ are arbitrary constants. Obviously, it'd be desirable to have written
$$
M = W\otimes\begin{bmatrix}
I_1 & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & I_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I suspect it'd be feasible at all for arbitrary constants. Any feedback/suggestion would be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To begin, note that there exists a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $P$ such that
$$
P^TMP = \pmatrix{
aI_1 & gI_1 & iI_1\\
g I_1 & c I_1 & kI_1\\
iI_1 & k I_1 & eI_1\\
&&& bI_2 & h I_2 & j I_2\\
&&& h I_2 & dI_2 & l I_2\\
&&& j I_2 & l I_2 & fI_2
}
$$
where the blank spaces denote zeros. We can write each of these blocks as a Kronecker product.  That is, we have
$$
P^TMP = \pmatrix{\pmatrix{a&g&i\\g&c&k\\i&k&e} \otimes I_1
\\ & \pmatrix{b&h&j\\h&d&l\\j&l&f} \otimes I_2}
$$